# Is there a concurrent version of this definition Java Guava collections Map

Tags: java, guava

Is there a concurrent version of this definition Guava collections Map ?

```
ListMultimap<DuplicateKey,Integer> map =
    Multimaps.newListMultimap(
    Maps.<DuplicateKey, Collection<Integer>>newTreeMap(),
    new Supplier<List<Integer>>() {
        public List<Integer> get() {
            return Lists.newArrayList();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should probably use MultimapBuilder instead of Multimaps.newListMultimap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no concurrent multimap implementation, but you can wrap it with [`Multimaps.synchronizedListMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/26.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#synchronizedListMultimap-com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap-) view, which:

> Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) multimap backed by the specified multimap.

In your case:

```
ListMultimap<DuplicateKey,Integer> synchronizedMultimap = 
    Multimaps.synchronizedListMultimap(map);
```

Read [complete javadoc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/26.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#synchronizedMultimap-com.google.common.collect.Multimap-) for caveats regarding synchronized access to views:

> In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that all access to the backing multimap is accomplished through the returned multimap.

Note that there'll be no general-purpose concurrent multimap implementation in Guava itself, according to [issue #135 on Github](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/135).

Comment: Reading of the map is actually only done by one thread, the issue is that writing could be multithreaded but I have to use a single threaded executor currently because not writign to a concurrent map. I don't generally like using synchronized but in this case sounds like the best choice, thanks.